# Understanding Big Oh Careercup Cracking Coding Interview

Tags: algorithm, big-o

There is an example question in the book Careercup Cracking Coding Interview(CCIS).

Print all positive integer solutions to the equation 
a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup>=c<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>3</sup>
and d are integers between 1 and 1000.

They gave three solutions two of which I will show here.

Example 1

`1 n = 1000
2 for a from 1 to n
3   for b from 1 to n
4     for c from 1 to n
S       for d from 1 to n
6         if a^3 + b^3 == c^3 + d^3
7              print a, b, c, d`

Example 2

`1 n = 1000
2 for a from 1 to n
3    for b from 1 to n
4       for c from 1 to n
5         d = pow(a3 + b3 - c3 , 1/3) // Will round to int
6            if a^3 + b^3 == c^3 + d^3 / / Validate that the value works
7                  print a, b, c, d`

The book states that the first question is O(n<sup>4</sup>) and the second one is O(n<sup>3</sup>). My question is why are they ignoring the complexity of `pow`

Comment: Probably the same reason the `a^3`, etc. are ignored...

Answer (score 1):

Big O expresses how the function grows with n. The pow function, especially with the second argument being 1/3, doesn't grow with n. That is to say pow is O(1). You can think of O(1) as an identity function. O(n) + O(1) = O(n) just like 2 + 0 = 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that they are not ignoring it, but assuming that the complexity is `O(1)`. The justification can be the following:

You need to make a function that calculates a cubic root (integer value) of some number from `0` to `1000^3`. How would you implement it? An easy way is a binary search (better ways exist, like numerical methods). How many iterations will it take you: `log2(1000^3)` which is approximately 30. So kind of `O(1)`.